# Is there a way to use a data generator in a KerasClassifier function?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence

According to this [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) file of `TensorFlow`, the input data may accept a data generator. However, the `KerasClassifier` explicitly accepts x and y attributes. How can I go around this since I would want to use a data generator for `KerasClassifier`?

When I am ingesting a data generator on `KerasClassifier`, I am getting an error that goes along the lines of "KerasClassifier is missing a y attribute".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is probably no.

The `KerasClassifier` class is meant to be used with *scikit-learn* APIs, which do not have a concept of a data generator.

So it has not be implemented, because there is no API to implement. If you want to train your model like this, you should use the Keras fit API directly.

Comment: Noted on this. I really wanted to use the KerasClassifier since I will be using scikit-learn frameworks. I want to combine the predictions of a Neural network frrom Keras and Logistic regression using StackingClassifier. Is there another way for me to combine predictions using StackingClassifier without having to use KerasClassifier?